# angularjs, browserify + underscore

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify

I have something like below on my angularjs app that works with browserify + gulp.

```
require('angular');
require('angular-resource');
require('angular-xeditable');
require('angular-spinner');

var app = angular.module('itembase', [
     require('angular-ui-router'),
    'ngResource',
    'xeditable',
    'angularSpinner'
]);
```

My question is on how to integrate underscore library into this environment.
I tried a few ways like, putting `require('underscore');` above `var _ = require('underscore');`, but it just doesn't seem to work.
The files are in the code but really visible in angularjs app.

Answer (score 1):

First of all underscore is not an angular module.
The solution would be to load underscore (with browserfy: `require('underscore')`) and then create a factory that returns underscore and makes it injectable in other angular components:

```
angular.module('itembase')
    .factory('_', function($window) {
        return $window._;
    });
```

After this, you only need to inject it in your component, as you do for any other:

```
angular.module('itembase')
    .controller('MyController', function(_) {
        _.each([1,2,3,4], function() {
            console.log('using underscore!!!');
        });
    });
```

The beauty of this approach is that your dependency is quite decoupled from the code and it is easy to test it or to change it without having to rewrite stuff later.

For example, if at the end of your project you realize that you use underscore only for iterating over arrays, you could reimplement your `_` factory like:

```
angular.module('itembase')
    .factory('_', function($window) {
        return {
            each: function(el, fn) {
                for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
                    fn(el[i], i, el);
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: sounds doable, i will give it a shot.

Comment: @gion_13 I'm trying to implement this answer but when creating the factory, on line 3, $window._ can't be reached. Is there something else that needs to be done? E.g. doesn't the browserified output file have to be added somewhere?

Comment: @fred in order for ` $window._` to be accessible you need to first load underscore (that defines  `window._`) and after that to execute your factory

Comment: underscore not found in window._

Comment: I suspect that you are using some kind of js module loader (like require.js) that tells underscore to not pin itself as a global variable. If you are using, or the project you are on uses or at least defines the `define` function, underscore will use that function to load itself into your app as a module, thus not being available on `window`. You can check it out at the bottom of the source file: http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js